# How to parse information contained in a file name

Tags: string-manipulation, data, parsing

I have a set of files containing my data, and the file-names contain relevant information that I would like to extract. What I have is:

```
SetDirectory["c:\\data"]
files = FileNames["201406*.dpt"];
Take[files, 3]
```

> ```
> {"20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer0Deg.dpt", 
>  "20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer90Deg-Temp100K.dpt", 
>  "20140606_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer0Deg-Temp10K.dpt"}
> ```

I would like to do something like

```
analysis /@ files
```

that does something like `"%d_%s_Polarizer%dDeg-Temp%dK.dpt", date, samplestr, angle, temp` and returns `{date, angle, temp}` as in

> ```
> {{{2014, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 0, Null},
>  {{2014, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 90, 100},
>  {{2014, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 0, 10}, ...
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm posting this variant in the hopes that it will be a little more educational.  Otherwise doesn't add anything over Kuba's version.

Generally, parsing can be done using [`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringCases.html).  You'll need to build up a [string expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatternsOverview.html) that describes the pattern of the file name, much the same way you'd write `"%d_%s_Polarizer%dDeg-Temp%dK.dpt"` when working with `scanf`.  Except here `%d` is called a [`NumberString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberString.html), `%s` is `__`, etc.  (Note: `scanf` wouldn't actually work here because it doesn't know that it has to stop reading the `%s` as soon as it encounters `_`.  `scanf` doesn't do pattern matching.)

So let's build up the pattern:

```
StringCases["20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer90Deg-Temp100K.dpt",
   date : NumberString ~~
   "_" ~~ name__ ~~
   "_Polarizer" ~~ angle : NumberString ~~
   "Deg-Temp" ~~ temp : NumberString ~~ 
   "K.dpt"   :>   {DateList[date], name, FromDigits[angle], FromDigits[temp]}
]

(* ==> {{{2014, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, "SampleName-C-vert", 90, 100}} *)
```

Since it's just a string of atomic constructs, it should be fairly self explanatory.

This basic pattern doesn't account for file names which do not have the `-Temp` part.  Fortunately the fix is easy: just make that part of the pattern optional, i.e. allow it to be [`Repeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html) zero or 1 times.

```
StringCases["20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer90Deg.dpt",
   date : NumberString ~~
   "_" ~~ name__ ~~
   "_Polarizer" ~~ 
   angle : NumberString ~~
   "Deg" ~~
   
   Repeated["-Temp" ~~ temp : NumberString ~~ "K", {0, 1}] ~~
   
   ".dpt" :> {DateList[date], name, angle, temp}]

(* ==> {{{2014, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, "SampleName-C-vert", "90", ""}} *)
```

If you are already familiar with regular expressions, or if you do not like the wordiness of Mathematica's pattern language, you can use [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegularExpression.html) to implement the same thing:

```
StringCases["20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer90Deg-Temp100K.dpt", 
  RegularExpression["([0-9]*)_(.*?)_Polarizer([0-9]*)Deg(-Temp([0-9]*)K)?\\.dpt"] :> 
  {"$1", "$2", "$3", "$5"}
]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {"20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer0Deg.dpt", 
  "20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer90Deg-Temp100K.dpt", 
  "20140606_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer0Deg-Temp10K.dpt"}
```

There are many ways. This one is not bulletproof but I think it should work with your data:

```
parse[string_] := ToExpression[{DateList@#, ##2}] & @@ Flatten[
 StringCases[string, x : NumberString ~~ # :> x] /. {}->"Null" & /@ {"_", "Deg", "K"}]


parse /@ list
```

> ```
> {{{2014, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 0, Null}, 
>  {{2014, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 90, 100},
>  {{2014, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 0, 10}}
> ```

Comment: I'm still trying to digest and understand how it works, but it does the job nicely. thanks!

Comment: @rhermans No problem ;) start with `StringCases[string, x : NumberString ~~ # :> x] & /@ {"_", "Deg", "K"}` and add the rest. In case of any troubles feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

```
  list = {"20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer0Deg.dpt", 
  "20140605_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer90Deg-Temp100K.dpt", 
  "20140606_SampleName-C-vert_Polarizer0Deg-Temp10K.dpt"};
```

Another way using `RegularExpressions`:

```
parse[str_]:=Module[{time,deg,temp},
    time=StringCases[str,RegularExpression["(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})"]:>{"$1","$2","$3",0,0,0}]//First;
    deg =StringCases[str,RegularExpression["(\\d+)Deg"]:> "$1"]/.{}->{Null}//First;
    temp=StringCases[str,RegularExpression["(\\d+)K"]:> "$1"]/.{}->{Null}//First;
    ToExpression/@{time,deg,temp}
]
parse/@list
```

> {{{2014,6,5,0,0,0},0,Null},{{2014,6,5,0,0,0},90,100},{{2014,6,6,0,0,0},0,10}}

And in a more condensed way:

```
parse2[str_String]:=
    StringCases[str
    ,RegularExpression["(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).+?(\\d+)Deg.*?((\\d+)K)?\\.dpt"]:>
         {Join[FromDigits/@{"$1","$2","$3"},{0,0,0}]
      ,FromDigits@"$4"
        ,"$6"/.""-> Null/.n_String:>FromDigits@n}
    ]
parse2/@list
```